# How do I get the last character of the cross-reference of an item in a multilayered list?

Tags: cross-referencing, amsart

Suppose we have the following code:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsaddr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in,top=3cm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{listings}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture} 
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[definition]
\newtheorem{note}[thm]{Note}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
 \begin{definition}
  Definition 1
 \end{definition} 
\section{Section 2}
 \begin{definition}
  Definition 2
 \end{definition}
 \begin{definition}
  Definition 3
 \end{definition}
\section{Section 3}
\begin{definition}  
 Definition 4
\end{definition}  
\begin{definition}  
 Definition 5
\end{definition}
\begin{definition}\label{def:6}
 Definition 6
 \begin{enumerate}    
 \item djdj
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item jffj
   \item krlf
   \item krfk
       \begin{enumerate}       
       \item dkdk
       \item krkd
       \item keld
       \item shsj
       \item krlf
       \end{enumerate}
   \item skxk \label{crit:d}
       \begin{enumerate}
       \item jddj \label{crit:di}
       \end{enumerate}
   \item kssk
   \end{enumerate}
 \item skdk
 \item krdk
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}
\section{Label of Criteria In The List of def. \ref{def:6}}
See sec. \ref{def:6}, crit. \ref{crit:d} \ref{crit:di}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question: When cross referencing `sec. 3, def. 6 crit. d(i)`, how do I get `(i)` instead of `1(d)i` (see the yellow highlighted field in the preceding screenshot)?

**Edit:** Made changes using a recent comment.

Comment: Please shown a complete example that demonstrates your issue. As it stands there really isn't enough information to trouble shoot.

Comment: By "When labeling", do you mean "When cross-referencing"? Please advise.

Comment: I’ve made changes.

Comment: The new code doesn't compile. Apart from a typo (`enuemrate`) and a missing `\end{definition}` directive, the code won't compile because you're somehow treating `section` as an environment instead of as a command. Please fix. Please also clarify *which* of the many list items you wish to cross-reference; for sure, I don't see an "a(iv)" item anywhere.

Comment: @Mico Does this work? It works on overleaf?

Comment: @Arbuja - I've edited your posting to sharpen the question. Please check if I got it right.

Comment: @Mico Yes, that’s correct.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you load the [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and use its `\setlist` macro to redefine the appearance of labels in level-1 thru level-3 enumerate environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%% I've tried to simplify and streamline the preamble
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\usepackage{enumitem} % see https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\upshape(\arabic*),
                      ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\upshape(\alph*),
                      ref=\arabic{enumi}\alph*}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\upshape(\roman*),
                      ref=(\roman*)}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}    % just for this example
\setcounter{definition}{5}

\begin{definition}\label{def:6}
Definition 6
 \begin{enumerate}    
 \item djdj* \label{crit:1}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item jffj
    \item krlf
    \item krfk
        \begin{enumerate}       
        \item dkdk
        \item krkd
        \item keld
        \item shsj
        \item krlf
        \end{enumerate}
    \item skxk* \label{crit:1d}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item jddj* \label{crit:1di}
        \end{enumerate}
    \item kssk
    \end{enumerate}
 \item skdk
 \item krdk
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\section{Labels of Criteria in the Numbered Lists in Definition \ref{def:6}}

\noindent
\ref{def:6} -- \ref{crit:1} -- \ref{crit:1d} -- \ref{crit:1di}

\end{document}
```